# Javascript big-data visualisation

Tags: javascript, performance, graph, visualization, bigdata

I'm about to develop a UI for medical research application. I need to make a time series line graph. Main issue is the amount of data:
5,000 points per graph, with a few of them displayed simultaneity. I’m expecting 50,000 points processed all together.

The question is what presentation library?
The main features I’m looking for are:  Handles huge data sets, Zoom, annotations, live update. 
I’m already looking into http://dygraphs.com/ and http://meteorcharts.com/
I wouldn't want any library that renders the data as DOM elements, or that uses SVG (from performance perspective)

Comment: So what did you go along with finally? I'm in the brainstorming stage for my big data project now. So many libraries out there, and seems like D3 might have a lot of possibility? My concern is speed though. I'm not sure how much number crunching should be kept on the server vs browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I'll give everyone my own answer to my question:
Dygraphs (http://dygraphs.com/) seems to be on the spot. The documentation, although a lot of apparent efforts, leaves a lot to be desired. But from performance, features and flexibility, it's the best I've seen. At least for my current project needs.
Way to go, Dygraphs!

Comment: How is your experience with it so far? Is it good for large datasets?

Comment: So far, it seems so. The problems I see are:   
1. Back-end delivery
2. The Dygraphs is not always simple to work with

Comment: 1. For backend delivery & crunching I'm still deciding between node.js or python. Node.js is great in all ways, except that it shouldn't be used for crunching (cpu intensive stuff), so I'm still researching if I should pass calculations over to python scripts or whether that would create further problems (maintenance, more layers etc), and instead handle on node.js layer. 2. For charts on client, since you said that Dygraphs is not always simple, would you recommend stuff like D3? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I don't have any experience with D3, so I can't say. What I can say is that to the best of my (limited) understanding D3 renders the data into DOM elements. Adding 200,000 or 10,000 elements to the DOM doesn't strike me as a good way to do

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out D3? I'm using that for a lot of graph visualization. It looks like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) example renders to svg.

[My stuff](https://github.com/brian-stinar/d3-graph-theory) renders to a SVG for force graph visualizations too, but it looks like D3 might be able to use [either a canvas or SVG](http://vallandingham.me/d3_without_svg.html), but I'm not positive about what all can be rendered to which. Honestly, I'd give D3 a try even with SVG, it might be fast enough. I remember reading something about someone simulating thousands of particles using D3's force graph visualizations without issues. It's SUPER easy to get your data into the right format for it to use.

Good luck!

Comment: Brian, tnx. AFAIK (and please correct me) D3 renders the data into DOM elements. Adding 50,000 elements to the DOM must take its toll!?

Comment: @Brian I suppose the hardware used comes into play when you do so much calculation on the browser. Probably a lower spec laptops and mobiles might slow down or hang .. thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a very similar application.

I am currently using [Flot](http://flotcharts.org) for the chart rendering. It handles annotations and zoom, take a look at their plugin library.

I recommend this [downsampling plugin](https://github.com/sveinn-steinarsson/flot-downsample/) which will speed up graph rendering. Rendering 5000 points on your graph is useless: you have less vertical pixels on your screen than that! so this library will only render those that actually have a visual importance.

This only gives you the graph. You may want some kind of dashboard to present all that... I am currently looking at [Grafana](http://grafana.org), which is used for a totally different purpose but makes awesome dashboards. It may be possible to "rip out" their dashboarding features (it uses Flot as well).

Another option is [Hightcharts](http://highcharts.com), but that's not free.

Comment: thanks! Flot is on my short list, and I'm revisiting it following your recommendation.

Comment: About **down-sampling**: Firstly, I planning on having zoom and pan enable, so I'll want more data then I show. I will need to fetch new data beyond little panning/zooming action, but at least I'll have some instant range.
***   
_Highcharts_ uses svg so I rolled it out.

Answer (score -1):

Check [raphael js](http://raphaeljs.com//) Library

> Raphaël is a small JavaScript library that should simplify your work with vector graphics on the web. If you want to create your own specific chart or image crop and rotate widget, for example, you can achieve it simply and easily with this library.

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Thanks for the fast reply! 
It seems, however, that raphael.js wouldn't be a good fit in this case as it is SVG-based